# Proof that a statement and its negation are both true?

Tags: real-analysis, logic, predicate-logic

I have a proof of a statement, and somehow a proof of its negation as well. I guess that the proof of its negation has mistakes?

**Statement** $\forall x \in \mathbb{R} \forall y \in \mathbb{R} \exists z \in \mathbb{R}   |x-z| < |x-y|$.

**Proof** Let $x,y \in \mathbb{R}$. Choose $z = \frac{x+y}{2}$.

**Negation** $ \exists x \in \mathbb{R} \exists y\in \mathbb{R} \forall z\in \mathbb{R} |x-z| \geq |x-y|$

**Proof** Let $x \in  \mathbb{R}$. Choose $x = y$. Let $z \in  \mathbb{R}$.
$|x-y| = 0 \leq |x-z|$. (This is actually a proof for the negation with $ \forall x...$, but for sure would show the actual negation as well.)

Comment: Let the two proofs fight it out. Suppose the second proof uses its clever idea and chooses $x=y$, and then the first proof uses *its* clever idea and chooses $z=\frac{x+y}2$. Do they get $|x-z|<|x-y|$ as the first proof wants? Or $|x-z|\geq|x-y|$ as the second proof wants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The original statement is false: what happens when $x=1=y ?$
2. For the negation, when adapting the proof of $\forall x$ to $\exists
       x,$ remember that $x$ is no longer arbitrary, so you do need to
   specify a particular choice of $x$ (remember, this value is fixed while the arbitrary variables that come after it are varying).

   So, a correct proof might instead go:

   Choose $(x,y)=(1,1)$ and let $z \in \mathbb{R}.$ Then $|x-y| = 0
   \leq |z-1|=|x-z|.$